# how to customize csl file such that can be used for my dissertation using libre office

Tags: file, using, mendeley, csl

Hi every one,
               I am interested in making the Reference file which exactly looks like in the picture, but the csl file that was available in mendeley[need in this style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVXh8.png)

but the csl file give like this

[csl file gives this format

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style xmlns="http://purl.org/net/xbiblio/csl" class="in-text" version="1.0" demote-non-dropping-particle="sort-only" default-locale="en-GB">
  <info>
    <title>The Open University - M801 - Research Project and Dissertation</title>
    <id>http://www.zotero.org/styles/the-open-university-m801</id>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/the-open-university-m801" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/harvard-anglia-ruskin-university" rel="template"/>
    <link href="http://www.open.ac.uk/library/help-and-support/referencing-styles" rel="documentation"/>
    <author>
      <name>Zsuzsa Nagy</name>
    </author>
    <category citation-format="author-date"/>
    <summary>Harvard style for the OU M801 TMAs and dissertation</summary>
    <updated>2012-09-27T22:06:38+00:00</updated>
    <rights license="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License</rights>
  </info>
  <macro name="cite-author">
    <choose>
      <if type="broadcast" match="any">
        <text variable="title" font-style="italic" suffix=","/>
      </if>
      <else-if type="bill legislation motion_picture" match="any">
        <text variable="title" font-style="italic" suffix="."/>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="legal_case" match="any">
        <text variable="title" font-style="italic"/>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <names variable="author">
          <name name-as-sort-order="all" and="text" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter-precedes-last="never" delimiter=", " suffix=","/>
          <label form="short" prefix=" "/>
          <substitute>
            <text macro="editor-detail"/>
            <text macro="anon" suffix=","/>
          </substitute>
        </names>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="editor-detail">
    <names variable="editor">
      <name name-as-sort-order="all" and="text" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter-precedes-last="never" delimiter=", "/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" " suffix=".," strip-periods="true"/>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="anon">
    <text term="anonymous" form="short" text-case="capitalize-first" strip-periods="true"/>
  </macro>
  <macro name="year-date">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill legislation" match="none">
        <choose>
          <if type="legal_case" match="any">
            <date variable="issued">
              <date-part name="year" prefix="[" suffix="]"/>
            </date>
          </if>
          <else-if variable="issued">
            <date variable="issued">
              <date-part name="year"/>
            </date>
          </else-if>
          <else-if variable="accessed">
            <choose>
              <if type="webpage song" match="any">
                <date variable="accessed">
                  <date-part name="year"/>
                </date>
              </if>
              <else>
                <text term="no date" form="short"/>
              </else>
            </choose>
          </else-if>
          <else>
            <text term="no date" form="short"/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="primary-title">
    <choose>
      <if type="chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia article-journal article-newspaper article-magazine paper-conference post-weblog post" match="any">
        <group>
          <text variable="title"/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="bill legal_case legislation motion_picture" match="any">
        <text variable="collection-number"/>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <choose>
          <if type="broadcast" match="none">
            <group delimiter=". ">
              <group delimiter=". ">
                <text variable="title" font-style="italic"/>
                <text macro="edition-no"/>
              </group>
              <text variable="collection-title"/>
            </group>
          </if>
        </choose>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="edition-no">
    <group delimiter=" ">
      <number variable="edition" form="ordinal"/>
      <text term="edition" form="short"/>
    </group>
  </macro>
  <macro name="translator">
    <names variable="translator">
      <name and="text" initialize-with="." delimiter=". " prefix="Translated by " suffix="."/>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="bill-detail">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill legislation" match="any">
        <group delimiter=". ">
          <text variable="section"/>
          <text variable="volume"/>
        </group>
      </if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="publisher">
    <choose>
      <if type="thesis">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <text variable="publisher"/>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="manuscript">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <text variable="archive"/>
          <group delimiter=". ">
            <text variable="archive_location"/>
            <text variable="publisher-place"/>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <group delimiter=": ">
          <text variable="publisher-place"/>
          <text variable="publisher"/>
        </group>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="container">
    <choose>
      <if type="chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia paper-conference" match="any">
        <group suffix=".">
          <text term="in" text-case="capitalize-first" suffix=": "/>
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <names variable="editor" delimiter=", ">
              <name and="text" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter-precedes-last="never" delimiter=", "/>
              <label form="short" prefix=", "/>
            </names>
            <group delimiter=", ">
              <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
              <text variable="collection-title"/>
              <choose>
                <if is-numeric="edition">
                  <group delimiter=" ">
                    <number variable="edition" form="ordinal"/>
                    <text term="edition" form="short"/>
                  </group>
                </if>
                <else>
                  <text variable="edition" suffix="."/>
                </else>
              </choose>
            </group>
          </group>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="bill legislation webpage" match="any">
        <text variable="container-title" suffix="."/>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="legal_case">
        <text variable="container-title"/>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="patent">
        <text variable="number" suffix="."/>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="motion_picture">
        <text variable="medium" prefix="[" suffix="]"/>
        <names variable="author">
          <name and="text" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter-precedes-last="never" delimiter=", " prefix=" Directed by " suffix="."/>
          <label form="short" prefix=" "/>
        </names>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <choose>
          <if variable="volume issue page" match="any">
            <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic" suffix=", "/>
          </if>
          <else>
            <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic" suffix="."/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="locator">
    <choose>
      <if type="article-journal article-newspaper article-magazine interview" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", " suffix=".">
          <group>
            <text variable="volume"/>
            <text variable="issue" prefix="(" suffix=")"/>
          </group>
          <choose>
            <if type="article-magazine article-newspaper interview" match="any">
              <date variable="issued" delimiter=" ">
                <date-part name="day"/>
                <date-part name="month" form="short"/>
              </date>
            </if>
          </choose>
          <choose>
            <if variable="page">
              <group>
                <label variable="page" form="short"/>
                <text variable="page"/>
              </group>
            </if>
          </choose>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="book chapter paper-conference manuscript entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia thesis motion_picture song report" match="any">
        <group suffix=".">
          <text variable="event" suffix=". "/>
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <text macro="publisher"/>
            <group>
              <label variable="page" form="short"/>
              <text variable="page"/>
            </group>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="broadcast">
        <group delimiter=". ">
          <text variable="event"/>
          <text macro="publisher"/>
          <group>
            <date variable="issued" delimiter=" ">
              <date-part name="day"/>
              <date-part name="month" form="short"/>
            </date>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author-short">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill broadcast legal_case legislation motion_picture" match="any">
        <text variable="title"/>
      </if>
      <else>
        <names variable="author">
          <name form="short" and="text" sort-separator=", " initialize-with="." delimiter-precedes-last="never" delimiter=", "/>
          <substitute>
            <names variable="editor"/>
            <text variable="title"/>
          </substitute>
        </names>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <citation et-al-min="3" et-al-use-first="1" disambiguate-add-year-suffix="true" collapse="year-suffix">
    <layout prefix="(" suffix=")" delimiter="; ">
      <group delimiter=", ">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <group font-weight="bold">
          <text macro="author-short"/>
          <text macro="year-date"/>
        </group>
        <group prefix=" ">
          <label variable="locator" form="short"/>
          <text variable="locator"/>
        </group>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </citation>
  <bibliography hanging-indent="false" et-al-min="5" et-al-use-first="1">
    <sort>
      <key macro="cite-author"/>
      <key macro="year-date"/>
      <key variable="title"/>
    </sort>
    <layout suffix=".">
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <text macro="cite-author"/>
        <choose>
          <if type="legal_case" match="any">
            <text macro="year-date"/>
          </if>
          <else>
            <text macro="year-date" suffix=". "/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </group>
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <text macro="primary-title" suffix="."/>
        <group delimiter=". " prefix=" ">
          <text macro="translator"/>
          <text macro="bill-detail"/>
          <text macro="container"/>
        </group>
        <text macro="locator"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
</style>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS4tO.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visual editor on [Citation Styles Website](http://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/)

It is not that intuitive at first, but once you got the hang of it, just find a similar style that you need and customize it to suit your needs.